# MDX Query - Difference Between [X].[Y].&[00] and [X].[Y].[00]

Tags: mdx, olap, cube, olap-cube

I have a cube I'm using MDX against. I have something like the below:

```
...[Source].[Source].&[UN]
```

What's the difference between this and

```
... [Source].[Source].[UN]
```

I've ran the code below to check the member key and member name. When I view the properties of each one, none of them have the ampersand under the `uniquename` field

```
SELECT    {} on 0, 
        [Source].[Source].MEMBERS 
        DIMENSION PROPERTIES 
             MEMBER_CAPTION, 
             UNIQUE_NAME, 
             LEVEL_UNIQUE_NAME, 
             MEMBER_KEY 
             ON 1 
FROM    [thisthat]
```

Does this mean the ampersand is redundant in this example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The & is not part of the key value:

1) [Source].&[UN] is referencing the member of the "source" hierarchy whose **key** value is "UN".

2) [Source].[UN] is referencing the member of the "source" hierarchy whose **name** value is "UN".

So in 1) the MDX server is performing a lookup by key and in 2) it is performing a lookup by name. Which one is faster depends on the implementation.

You might get different results in case **name** and **key** uniqueness logics are not the same.

Comment: spot on answer - yes name could be duplicated in the cube - key is unique. Name is definitely more readable - and because we do not repeat names I usually use them for readability.